# Как придать отдельные стили для Left и Right данных в таблице?

Tags: javascript, css

Код генерирует `2` цифровых значения, разделенные восклицательным знаком, каждый из которых состоит из `5` цифр. Мне необходимо разделить эти значения в таблице, чтобы можно было индивидуально придать стиль каждой из `2` комбинаций.
За левые `5` цифр отвечает `Left`.
За правые `5` цифр отвечает `right`
Спасибо

```js
var tableEl;
 
function generate()
{    
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable"),
        numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i),
        result = [],
        qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);

    myTable.innerHTML = '';
    tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
    myTable.appendChild(tableEl);

    while(result.length < qnt)
    {
        var left = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-'),
            right = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-');

        //чтобы не были равны между собой
        if(left == right)
            continue;

        result.push([left, right]);
        fillTableWithContent(left + ' ! ' + right);
    }
}

function shuffle(arr)
{
    return arr.map(el => {
        return {
            item: el,
            sort: Math.random()
        }
    }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function fillTableWithContent(content)
{
    tableEl.insertRow(tableEl.rows.length)
        .insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
}
```

```html
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Кол-во комбинаций" style="background: #ffffff!important;color: #8f2d00!important;font-size: 20px!important;"/>
<input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Получить комбинации" onclick="generate()" />

<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так. Числа раскидываются в разные `td` что дает возможность применить разные стили к ним.

```js
var tableEl;
 
function generate()
{    
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable"),
        numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i),
        result = [],
        qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);

    myTable.innerHTML = '';
    tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
    myTable.appendChild(tableEl);

    while(result.length < qnt)
    {
        var left = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-'),
            right = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-');

        //чтобы не были равны между собой
        if(left == right)
            continue;

        result.push([left, right]);
        fillTableWithContent(left, right);
    }
}

function shuffle(arr)
{
    return arr.map(el => {
        return {
            item: el,
            sort: Math.random()
        }
    }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function fillTableWithContent(left, right)
{
    var tr = tableEl.insertRow(tableEl.rows.length);
    tr.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(left));
    tr.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(right));
}
```

```html
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Кол-во комбинаций" style="background: #ffffff!important;color: #8f2d00!important;font-size: 20px!important;"/>
<input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Получить комбинации" onclick="generate()" />

<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Comment: Михаил, Да, вы разделили значения, но классы не стоят у td

Comment: ну их не обязательно добавлять, можно и так, просто я рассчитывал на то, что вы и сами их добавите:
`<style>
    tr > td:first-child {
        color:red;
    }
    tr > td:last-child {
        color:green;
    }
</style>`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!